# Given an array of N integers, and an integer K, find the number of pairs of elements in the array whose sum is equal to K

Tags: python, loops

Problem Statement:- Given an array of N integers, and an integer K, find the number of pairs of elements in the array whose sum is equal to K.

```
**def countpairs(x,length,sum):
    count = 0
    for i in range(0,length):
       for j in range(i+1,length):
            print(x[i],x[j])   
            if(x[i]+x[j]==sum):
                count+=1
    print(count)


x  = [1, 1, 1, 1]
sum = 2
length=len(x)
countpairs(x,length,sum)
Output:= 6**
This is My solution used in VS code.
```

My Question:- whenever I am running the same code in gfg it is not accepting the code giving me this error. I even have tried the same code in the online compiler there also it is running correctly.

```
This Is the gfg code which i have written 
class Solution:
    def getPairsCount(self, arr, K, N):
        count = 0
        for i in range(0,N):
           for j in range(i+1,N): 
                if(arr[i]+arr[j]==K):
                    count+=1
        return count


#Initial Template for Python 3

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tc = int(input())
    while tc > 0:
        n, k = list(map(int, input().strip().split()))
        arr = list(map(int, input().strip().split()))
        ob = Solution()
        ans = ob.getPairsCount(arr, n, k)
        print(ans)
        tc -= 1


Error
if(arr[i]+arr[j]==K):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: You're passing arguments `arr, n, k` to a function whose parameters are `arr, K, N`; this is giving the indexerror.

Comment: Argument  name can be different, if it was the problem of argumnet then the code will not work in vs code.

Comment: I'm aware that argument names and parameter names can be different. My point was that this problem was caused by typos. Your 'vscode' and other code snippet are completely different, and only one has this typo of swapping n and k

Comment: @kcsquared got your point

Comment: What is gfg in gfg code?

Answer (score 2):

There's no added value in using a class for this. You just need:-

```
def getPairsCount(arr, K):
  count = 0
  for i in range(len(arr)-1):
    if arr[i] + arr[i+1] == K:
      count += 1
  return count
```

EDIT:

Previous answer assumed that only adjacent elements were to be considered. If that's not the case then try this:-

```
import itertools

def getPairsCount(arr, K):
    count = 0
    for c in itertools.combinations(sorted(arr), 2):
        if c[0] + c[1] == K:
            count += 1
    return count

data = [1, 2, 1, 4, -1]
print(getPairsCount(data, 3))
```

Comment: This Is giving output as: = 0

Comment: What it returns will depend on the data you pass to it. For example *getPairsCount([1, 2, 1, 4, -1], 3)* returns 3 as I believe it should

Comment: I interpret a "pair of elements" as meaning two adjacent elements. Perhaps if the question had not been so ambiguous, I might have presented a viable solution. Maybe my understanding of the English language is not as good as it might be

Comment: okay, I will delete my comment about wrong answer. I think it is ambiguous in that case, maybe you are right @DarkKnight. But the way, OP compared all pairs, it seems it is any pair not just adjacent

Comment: thanks for the edit!  yes, this makes it clearer

Answer (score 1):

We do not need two loops for this question. Here is something that runs in `O(n)`:

```
def countpairs(list_,K):
    count = 0
    set_ = set(list_)
    pairs_ = []
    
    for val in list_:
        if K - val in set_:
            # we ensure that pairs are unordered by using min and max
            pairs_.append ( (min(val, K-val), max(val, K-val)) )
            count+=1

    set_pairs = set(pairs_)
    
    print ("Pairs which sum up to ",K," are: ", set_pairs)

    return len(set_pairs)




x  = [1,4,5,8,2,0,24,7,6]
sum_ = 13
print ("Total count of pairs summming up to ", sum_, " = ", countpairs(x, sum_))
```

Output:

```
Pairs which sum up to  13  are:  {(6, 7), (5, 8)}
Total count of pairs summming up to  13  =  2
```

The idea is that if two values should sum to a value `K`, we can iterate through the array and check if there is another element in the array which when paired with the current element, sums up to `K`. The inner loop in your solution can be replaced with a search using the `in`. Now, we need this search to be fast (`O(1) per element`), so we create a set out of our input array (`set_` in my example).

Comment: Surely the pairs 5,8 and 8,5 are (effectively) the same. I contend that the answer to the original question using your data should be 2

Comment: Yes, that is true. Thanks for highlighting!  I will add an edit if a,b and b,a are different,

Comment: done; I used min and max to ensure that the ordering is removed

Comment: The question is ambiguous, but how this problem is usually presented, elements which appear multiple times in the array are counted multiple times, e.g. the answer for ([5,5,8], 13) is 2

Answer (score 0):

```
def solve(a,K):
    freq = {}
    for v in a:
        if v in freq:
            freq[v] += 1
        else:
            freq[v] = 1
    for i in range(len(set(a))):
        res += freq[a[i]] * freq[K - a[i]]
    return res 

a = [int(v) for v in input().split()]
K = int(input())
print(solve(a,K))
# Time Complexity : O(N)
# Space Complexity : O(1)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def solve(a,K):
    freq = {}
    for v in a:
        if v in freq:
            freq[v] += 1
        else:
            freq[v] = 1
    for i in range(len(set(a))):
        res += freq[a[i]] * freq[K - a[i]]
    return res

a = [int(v) for v in input().split()]
K = int(input())
print(solve(a,K))
```

Comment: won't work, res not defined in solve function